# A movie about an alien and an alien cop that chases him

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Might be a little vague - from what I recall it might be mid 80's to early 90's, English speaking, american origin, live action movie, about an (evil) alien that uses humans as hosts (and can change his host), the alien itself looks like a small (half-basketball size) grey blob, and he's chased by some sort of an alien cop (humanoid) that has a silver phaser-looking gun that shoots a red ray/laser,I remember the final scene being the injured alien cop shooting the exposed alien blob, which had just exited his dying host on some sort of conference stage/platform, I was pretty young so I can't recall much more.
Any help would be much appreciated :)!

Comment: same movie, but the explanation details I remembered differ, and (imho) seem more  detailed. should that be considered a dup? since people looking for it might find it easier to relate to this explanation?

Comment: @TommySM [Our policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/) is to close ID questions as dupes when they're looking for the same work; having the two questions linked together actually *helps* searchability, because now your memory of the film and Major Stackings' are both here with a great big notice saying "These are the same thing"

Comment: Since both questions have the same accepted answer (*The Hidden*), then they are considered duplicates. This won't delete your question, so it remains searchable and able to help others who may be looking for the same movie.

Comment: From the title, I would've guessed "I Come in Peace" starring Dolph Lundgren... although I prefer to remember it by its original title of "Dark Angel".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be the movie [The Hidden](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/) from 1987 starring Kyle MacLachlan.

> An alien parasite with the ability to possess human bodies goes on a violent crime spree in LA, pursued by a human cop and an alien cop inhabiting a human body.

you can find the full movie on youtube.

the final scene where you see the alien parasite exit his dying human body and it is killed with a small silver laser gun is at 1:28:30

Comment: Apparently based on the Hal Clement book "Needle".

Comment: Notable for Claudia Christian in a prominent role. She later played Susan Ivanova in _Babylon 5_.